# TBB crashed when loading lib_tbbxxx.so dynamic libs

Tags: c++, tbb

enviroment:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```

background：
I build and link tbb statically in my program, but if my server already install libtbb-dev, my program will crashed in load libtbb_xxx.so, here is the `strace` command output, and remove  libtbb-dev it works well:

```
futex(0x23bbb40, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 24
fstat(24, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=40010, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 40010, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 24, 0) = 0x7f505ae66000
close(24)                               = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtbbmalloc.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 24
read(24, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0000e\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(24, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=132976, ...}) = 0
close(24)                               = 0
munmap(0x7f505ae66000, 40010)           = 0
--- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SEGV_MAPERR, si_addr=0x390} ---
+++ killed by SIGSEGV (core dumped) +++
Segmentation fault
```

TBB version: v2021.6.0-rc1

compile params:

```
    CMAKE_COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND}
    CMAKE_ARGS 
        -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=<INSTALL_DIR> 
        -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF
        -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-D__TBB_DYNAMIC_LOAD_ENABLED=0
        -DTBB_ENABLE_IPO=OFF
        -DTBB_TEST=OFF 
        -DTBB_EXAMPLES=OFF 
        -DTBB_BENCH=OFF
```

Is anyone help?
Thanks first!

Comment: If the program is linked with all static modules, why does it try and load `libtbb_xxx.so` is one of the (possibly external modules) not statically linked ?

Comment: @RichardCrittenn That's what I'm confused about

Comment: It would be really helpful if you provide the complete code.